How to render the word WOULD / MUST in the Reported Speech?
I.
If I have this sentence in the direct speech:
She said: "I would like a cake."
How to change the word "would" in the reported speech? I've heard that the word "would" doesn't change... but not quite sure about that.
Is this correct?
Reported speech:
She said that she would like a cake.
Or is this correct?
Reported speech:
She said that she would have liked a cake.
II.
I have this sentence is the Direct Speech:
He said, "It must be cold outside."
How to change the word "must"?
Which variant is correct?
1. He said (that) it must be cold outside.
2. He said it had to be cold outside.
3. He said it must have been cold outside.
I've read this article Modal verbs (must, may, would) in reported-speech backshift, but couldn't understand the explanation as it wasn't clear enough for me. If you don't mind, please give a short answer at first and only then explain if you would like to.
Thx beforehand.

She said that she would have liked a cake is the reported speech version if what she actually said was "I would have liked a cake". It's the same for your second example - there's no reason to switch to a Perfect form just because it's reported speech. Well, it's a bit more than "no reason" - if you do that, you're changing the meaning, so if you want to be accurate, just don't do it.

The switch from Present to Past is illustrated by He said "My name is John" which can optionally be backshifted to He said his name was John rather than He said his name is John.
